# C# counter to count up to a target number

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to find out if anyone knows about an already existing c# plugin that will count up to a target number at a specified speed.

I'd like to be able to specify:

- The start number
- The end number
- The amount of time it should take to get from start to end.
- A custom callback function that can execute when a counter is
  finished.

I found these plugins one for javascript and one for asp.net:

> https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/
>
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wisej-2-CountUp/

I am making an application with asp.net core and blazor, I need something that fits blazor since it is a new technology and there is not much information on how to implement javascript plugins

> if they had any example of how to implement countup.js in asp.net core
> they would help me a lot

Comment: Please research on how to use npm packages in Blazor. If you learn that, rest is just implementing countUp.js.

Comment: I this a school project?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion already install npm in asp.net core to use with blazor

Comment: CountUp.js uses Easing. If that is required then your best course is a Blazor wrapper around the js.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a timer service that can serve you on many occasions:

Create the service class:

```
public class BlazorTimer
    {
        private Timer _timer;

        internal void SetTimer(double interval)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(interval);
            _timer.Elapsed += NotifyTimerElapsed;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void NotifyTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnElapsed?.Invoke();
        }

        public event Action OnElapsed;
    }
```

Add the service to the DI container, in the Program.Main method, as transient:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(config =>
        {
            var blazorTimer = new BlazorTimer();
            blazorTimer.SetTimer(1000);
            return blazorTimer;
        });
```

### Usage

```
@page "/"

@implements IDisposable
@inject BlazorTimer Timer

@count.ToString()


@code{
private int count = 0;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Timer.OnElapsed += NotifyTimerElapsed;

    base.OnInitialized();
}

private void NotifyTimerElapsed()
{
    // Note: WebAssembly Apps are currently supporting a single thread, which 
    // is why you don't have to call
    // the StateHasChanged method from within the InvokeAsync method. But it 
    // is a good practice to do so in consideration of future changes, such as 
    // ability to run WebAssembly Apps in more than one thread.
    InvokeAsync(() => { count++; StateHasChanged(); });
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Timer.OnElapsed -= NotifyTimerElapsed;
}
```

}

Comment: [Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines)

Comment: @Henk Holterman: "Services resolved from the container should never be disposed by the developer." And where exactly do you see my code disposes of the BlazorTimer service ? Unsubscribing event handler in the Dispose method implemented in a Blazor component by no means disposes of the  BlazorTimer service...Please create a new question so I can expand on this.

Comment: No, you're right about that. But the BlazorTimer is leaking the _timer. Timer is IDisposable.